# 一部ページのみhttpsへリダイレクトさせる方法（サクラサーバー・Wordpress導入）

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, https

サクラのレンタルサーバー利用、Wordpressを導入し独自SSLを適用しました。
contactページだけhttpsへリダイレクトしたいのですが、上手く出来ず自己解決できませんでした。
.htaccessに以下の様に入力し、ルートフォルダへアップしたところ、
contactページは、HTTPS・HTTP共にトップページへ飛んでしまいます。

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#HTTPでアクセスされた場合、
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Sakura-Forwarded-For} ^$
#このページだけHTTPSへ飛ばす
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/contact/.*$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

ここまで入力した場合は、contactはhttpsへリダイレクトします。
以下のコードを追加すると、contactがトップページへリダイレクトしてしまいます。

```
#HTTPSでアクセスされた場合、
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Sakura-Forwarded-For} !^$
#このページ以外HTTPSへ飛ばす
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/contact/.*$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L] 

# 元からあるワードプレスのコード
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

コードが合っているかは不明ですが、模索するうちに自己解決いたしました。
もっとスマートな方法があるかもしれませんが、希望の挙動をしたコードは以下です。

```
RewriteEngine On
#contactページにhttpでアクセスした場合
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/contact/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Sakura-Forwarded-For} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#トップページ以外にhttpsでアクセスした場合
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/contact/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Sakura-Forwarded-For} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#トップページにhttpsでアクセスした場合
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Sakura-Forwarded-For} !^$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/ [L,R=301]
```